# How to setup Mock to already present object as defaul behavior?

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, moq

I can do this:

```
var alreadyPresentMyClass = GetMyClass();//retrieving MyClass from somewhere

var mock = new Mock<IMyClass>();
mock.Setup(x=> x.Method1()).Callback(alreadyPresentMyClass.Method1);
mock.Setup(x=> x.Method2()).Callback(alreadyPresentMyClass.Method2);
....
mock.Setup(x=> x.Method666()).Throws(new Exception("BAD LUCK")); //this is only method which is throwing error in this test. So the only one I want to setup.
....
mock.Setup(x=> x.Method1000()).Callback(alreadyPresentMyClass.Method1000);
```

How one can remove unnecessary garbage of setuping thousands of methods, and instead setup it based on another object as default, like this:

```
var mock = Mock.CreateByAlreadyPresent(GetMyClass());
mock.Setup(x=> x.Method666()).Throws(new Exception("BAD LUCK"));
```

Any thoughts? I can write reflection method myself, but is there already such method?

Comment: I spend some time investigating this and I think currently it is not possible. Mock use dynamic proxy to setup interceptors which will actually alter the call if you setup the method. There is no way currently to hook up into that mechanism and alter it based on the existing object.

Comment: Uhm, but you can enumerate methods through reflection and construct respective linq mocks, no? I think the problem it is not implemented yet, rather than it can't be (because it can, I will add implementation later)

Comment: sure you can do that. I was more thinking moq out of the box doesn't provide solution. I am in doubt if moq4 will ever support this, you can ask there directly. The new moq should support this oob but have to take closer look at that.

Answer (score -2):

You would use the property CallBase for that:

```
var mock = new Mock<MyClass> { CallBase = true };
mock.Setup(x => x.Method666()).Throws(new Exception("BAD LUCK"));
```

The other methods will have their default behaviour.

Comment: I don't see using predefined class: you should use GetMyClass() which in essential can be IoC framework which will return *something* of interface IMyClass.